# How to open PDF Document programatically without saving it?

Tags: c#, pdf, web, spire

I have PDF document saved into my PDFs folder. I have created one function whose duty is to load the PDF into `PdfDocument` class, add some styles on `runtime`, save it back as temporary file and preview it in `WebClient`. My logic is working absolutely fine. I want to eliminate saving it back as temporary file. I want to directly preview it without saving, is it possible? I searched online but didn't get any good source. Following is my code:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
pdf.LoadFromFile("MyFile.pdf");
pdf.SaveToFile("ModifiedMyFile.pdf"); // Eliminate this part
WebClient User = new WebClient();
Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData("ModifiedMyFile.pdf");
if (FileBuffer != null)
{
  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
  Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to spire's documentation, you have two ways to do that

Using SaveToHttpResponse() method

https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/How-to-Create-PDF-Dynamically-and-Send-it-to-Client-Browser-Using-ASP.NET.html

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
pdf.LoadFromFile("MyFile.pdf");

.... edit the document

pdf.SaveToHttpResponse("sample.pdf",this.Response, HttpReadType.Save);
```

Or, if the built-in method doesn't work, try to use a memory stream instead of a temporary file.

https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Document-Operation/Save-PDF-file-to-Stream-and-Load-PDF-file-from-Stream-in-C-.NET.html

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

.... edit the document

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  pdfDocument.SaveToStream(ms);

  Byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();

  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  Response.AddHeader("content-length", bytes.Length.ToString());
  Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
}
```